# How do I change the default color of desktop window decorations on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, user-interface

On Windows 8, all of my windows are bordered in a peachy red color. This is the default that was set by the manufacturer. I don't like the color and want to change it. It is particularly bad with IE 10, but the same color appears around any window on the desktop (this question is not about Modern UI / Metro).

How can I change the color of the window decorations on Windows 8?

When I started up the computer, I chose a nice cool blue for my theme color, which is only present on the start page.  Once I go into an active window, the borders and dropdown backgrounds turn to red.

I do not know how to take a screenshot on Windows 8, either. Please reply in the comments if you can guide me on how to do this.

Comment: Uhm... could you include a screenshot? Is your Windows 8 colour theme red? IE 10 does not default to red AFAIK.

Comment: You're going to need to be more descriptive "this hideous red default...", what hideous red default color?

Comment: Just got a new laptop and the print screen is the same as the end button.  I do not know how to copy a screen shot on this,  Basically the task bars are peachy red and killing my eyes.

Comment: I read something in another post about IE 10 using the dominant color of the favicon. Someone whose favicon was grey was still getting peach as his theme color. Something about the 10*10 or 15*15 pixel. This is all over my head.

Comment: To take a screenshot you might need to press `Fn` while pressing the End/PrntScr key. You can also run the "snipping tool" (search for it from the start screen/start menu) and take a screenshot with that. Without a screenshot it's impossible for us to tell what you're talking about.

Comment: the default color on my new laptop running windows 8 is red.  I want to change that.

Comment: @Guest Right click in open space on desktop -> Left click `Personalize` -> Left click `Window Color` -> Left click any color you want -> Left click `Save changes`

Comment: Major revisions to the question. Please vote to reopen. I recommend that @defaultNINJA post his description of the solution (*more detail, please!*) as an answer.

Comment: FINALLY a screenshot
![screenshot of RED windows][1]

Well, Maybe not, the website wouldn't let me post the screenshot. It said I need at least 10 reputation to post images.  Not very useful.  So just imagine if you will, the window you are looking at right now with red borders.

If anyone knows how to change this please let me know.  Thank You.

Comment: WHAT A COOL SITE!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Right click on the blank Desktop
- Select "Personalize"
- Click "Colors" at the bottom center of the window
- Click the color you want and then "Save changes"

Alternately you can click

- In the window that comes up, click "Windows" under "Windows Default Themes".

This will completely reset Windows styles to the Windows 8 default.